# Xamarin.Forms ZXing BarcodeReaderGeneric returns null when scanning an image in the gallery

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing, zxing.net, zxing.net.mobile

I am developing a barcode reader with Xamarin.Forms. And I'm trying to scan the image on Android device.

First I select the image from the gallery with Xamarin.Essentials MediaPicker and from the path of this image I get an RGBLuminance with the Dependency class.

Then I am trying to decode this RGBLuminance with the **Decode()** method of the ZXing **BarcodeReaderGeneric** class. However, the result always returns null.

It is my demo project : https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AFLjjM91wgZkBGU&cid=58BE2C2C3447FFA2&id=58BE2C2C3447FFA2%219829&parId=root&action=locate

Command in the ViewModel class:

```cs
        public ICommand PickCommand => new Command(PickImage);
        private async void PickImage()
        {
            var pickResult = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
            {
                Title = "Select a barcode."
            });
            var path = pickResult.FullPath;

            var RGBLuminance = DependencyService.Get<ILuminance>().GetRGBLuminanceSource(path);
            var reader = new BarcodeReaderGeneric();
            var result = reader.Decode(RGBLuminance); // result always null.
        }
```

Method of Dependency class in Android:

```cs
        public RGBLuminanceSource GetRGBLuminanceSource(string imagePath)
        {
            
            if (File.Exists(imagePath))
            {
                Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imagePath);
                List<byte> rgbBytesList = new List<byte>();
                for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
                    {
                        var c = new Android.Graphics.Color(bitmap.GetPixel(x, y));
                        rgbBytesList.AddRange(new[] { c.A, c.R, c.G, c.B });
                    }
                }
                byte[] rgbBytes = rgbBytesList.ToArray();
                return new RGBLuminanceSource(rgbBytes, bitmap.Height, bitmap.Width, RGBLuminanceSource.BitmapFormat.RGB32);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Serkan Seker, Could you please post the full error log about this problem? It will give us a clue to the problem. If it is convenient for you, could you please post a basic demo to githhub or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Hi @JessieZhang-MSFT I prepared a demo project. https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AFLjjM91wgZkBGU&cid=58BE2C2C3447FFA2&id=58BE2C2C3447FFA2%219829&parId=root&action=locate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the line

`return new RGBLuminanceSource(rgbBytes, bitmap.Height, bitmap.Width, RGBLuminanceSource.BitmapFormat.RGB32);`

to

`return new RGBLuminanceSource(rgbBytes, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, RGBLuminanceSource.BitmapFormat.RGB32);`

And to be more accurate with the RGB format you should

- change RGBLuminanceSource.BitmapFormat.RGB32 to RGBLuminanceSource.BitmapFormat.ARGB32
- or change rgbBytesList.AddRange(new[] { c.A, c.R, c.G, c.B }); to rgbBytesList.AddRange(new[] { c.R, c.G, c.B, c.A });

Comment: Thank you. Does different BitmapFormat affect the result when scanning barcodes?

Comment: It depends. The luminance source in RGB32 mode uses the first three bytes as R, G and B channel. The fourth byte (alpha channel) is ignored. If you build the array in ARGB order the alpha value is interpreted as red channel, the red channel as green, the green channel as blue and the blue channel would be ignored. That leads to a different grayscale image and in some cases to a different monochrome bit matrix. Some images, perhaps with low contrast or similar, may fail.

Comment: What is the best BitmapFormat setting to cover all barcode types?  Both black-white and color barcodes are available.

Comment: The barcode types don't depend on the bitmap format. You have to select a format that fits your byte array.
You can alternatively use the barcode reader class ZXing.Android.BarcodeReader from the android binding package https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Bindings.Android/.
Your code would look like the following in that case:

´´´
if (File.Exists(imagePath))
{
 Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imagePath);
 var reader = new ZXing.Android.BarcodeReader();
 var result = reader.Decode(bitmap); 
}
´´´

Comment: What I don't understand is that one image of different sizes with the same content is decoded correctly, while the other returns null. Why is this happening?

Comment: For an answer, I need these two image files.

Comment: Can you try with pictures below?

Comment: Both images work for me. I tried decoding with the Windows Forms sample application from the ZXing.Net project. I have no idea what's wrong in your case. Did you try the class ZXing.Android.BarcodeReader class from the android binding package?

Comment: ZXing.Android.BarcodeReader cannot decode a barcode image taken from the camera. Also, how can I use the BarcodeReader class on iOS? I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms project. So I want to add the same feature to the iOS side.

Comment: In that case you should try the ZXing.Net.Mobile project: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this pictures?

[Picture One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQius.jpg)
[Picture Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PycSB.jpg)